# Does AnalyserNode update its "current frequency data" continuously?

Tags: javascript, performance, fft, web-audio-api

I have read the section on [The AnalyserNode Interface](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-analysernode-interface) on the W3C docs, which states that the `AnalyserNode` will pass the input audio to the output untouched. It also describes the [process of computing its "current frequency data"](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#current-frequency-data).

I am wondering whether this processing of the input audio is done continuously or on-demand, f.i. when `getFloatFrequencyData()` is called.

Does anyone know? Is it browser specific?

Comment: it doesn't matter to scripts, so it's likely left to implementer discretion, judging from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked Paul Adenot](https://twitter.com/padenot/status/758295520678936576) who was kind enough to link me to the source of Chrome and Firefox respectively:

- Chrome: Updated when requested. https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webaudio/RealtimeAnalyser.cpp?cl=GROK&gsn=discreteTimeConstantForSampleRate&rcl=1469603944&l=209
- Firefox: Updated when requested. http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/webaudio/AnalyserNode.cpp#197

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the browser, but as a performance optimization, it could be done only on demand.  Of course, the node needs to keep enough information around to do the computation on demand, but that should be much cheaper than continuously computing the frequency data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Raymond. Are you reasoning about possible answers to the question? Or are you implying that you can work around the fact that it is continuously computing the frequency data?

Comment: It doesn't have to continuously compute to pass data from input to output.  Only on demand using the current and/or last few buffers of samples.  An implementation decision that could legally differ.

Comment: @hotpaw2 See the answer above!